# How to split string with different phones using re?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

For example there are such phones:

```
phones = '+35(123) 456 78 90 (123) 555 55 55  (908)985 88 89   (593)592 56 95'
```

I need to get:

```
phones_list = ['+35(123) 456 78 90', '(123) 555 55 55', '(908)985 88 89', (593)592 56 95]
```

Trying to solve using `re`, but quite a hard task to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach uses the `+` or `(` to signal the beginning of a phone number.  It does not require multiple-spaces:

```
>>> phones = '+35(123) 456 78 90 (123) 555 55 55  (908)985 88 89   (593)592 56 95'
>>> re.split(r' +(?=[(+])', phones)
['+35(123) 456 78 90', '(123) 555 55 55', '(908)985 88 89', '(593)592 56 95']
```

This splits the string based on one-or-more spaces followed by either `(` or `+`.

In the regular expression, `+` matches one or more spaces.  `(?=[(+])` is a look-ahead.  It requires that the spaces be followed by either `(` or `+` but does not consume the `(` or `+`.  Because we are using a look-ahead instead of a plain match, the the leading `(` and `+` remain part of the phone number.